# multiple input foreach on php

Tags: php, html, foreach

I´m not an advanced php coder so I need some help here. and i just continue this job for another people who i can't contact anymore.
i need some help.

this is my code

```
        if($_POST['nilai']!="" )
        {
        echo "Input Absensi telah Berhasil";
            foreach($_POST['nilai'] as $idKhs=>$nilai){
            $jf->p['jfSql']->ubah('khs',array('ke_1'=>$nilai));
            $jf->p['jfSql']->ubah('khs',array('ke_2'=>$nilai));
            $jf->p['jfSql']->ubah('khs',array('ke_3'=>$nilai));
            $jf->p['jfSql']->jika('id_khs',$idKhs);
            $jf->p['jfSql']->sqlProses();
            }

        }
        else
        {....
```

and this another the function

```
<?php
                if($dataNilai!=""){
                foreach($dataNilai as $isi){
                $no++;
                if($no%2 ==0){
                    $tbclass = "alt";
                    $tbnoclass = "noalt";
                    }else{
                    $tbclass = "";
                    $tbnoclass = "no";
                    }
             ?>
            <tr>
              <th scope="row" class="<?php echo $tbnoclass ?>"><?php echo $no ?>.</th>
              <td class="<?php echo $tbclass ?>"><?php echo $isi['nim'] ?></td>
              <td class="<?php echo $tbclass ?>"><?php echo $isi['nama'] ?></td>
              <td align="center" class="<?php echo $tbclass ?>"><select name="nilai[<?php echo $isi['id_khs'] ?>]">
                <option value="Hadir" <?php if($isi['ke_1']=="Hadir") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Hadir</option>
                <option value="Izin" <?php if($isi['ke_1']=="Izin") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Izin</option>
                <option value="Sakit" <?php if($isi['ke_1']=="Sakit") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Sakit</option>
                <option value="Absen" <?php if($isi['ke_1']=="Absen") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Absen</option>
              </select>
              </td>
              <td align="center" class="<?php echo $tbclass ?>"><select name="nilai[<?php echo $isi['id_khs'] ?>]">
                <option value="Hadir" <?php if($isi['ke_2']=="Hadir") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Hadir</option>
                <option value="Izin" <?php if($isi['ke_2']=="Izin") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Izin</option>
                <option value="Sakit" <?php if($isi['ke_2']=="Sakit") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Sakit</option>
                <option value="Absen" <?php if($isi['ke_2']=="Absen") echo "selected=\"selected\""; ?>>Absen</option>
              </select>
```

the problem is that the input that entered the database is only the last column. in this case just go to "ke_3". for tables_1 and 2 there are no changes.

Comment: 2 `<select name=` same names

Comment: and where code I have to change

Comment: your question related to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34617755/form-inside-foreach-loop-php)